# Bootstrap validator with custom validation

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm very new to jquery and bootstrap. I have tried everything I can find. My scenario: when a users clicks 'Submit' the bootstrap validator validates the page and if all is ok, then it calls a method in my code-behind. I also need to incorporate custom validators.

The problem is when I click 'Submit' the validation occurs but the messages are in grey as opposed to red. When I type in a required field, it does turn green with the checkbox.
However, if i remove the 'validator()' section with the custom validators in it, the screen then works fine, but I obviously have no custom validators.

I have tried all different scenarios, and cannot get it to work. Any insight or help would be much appreciated!

My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Test2</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Global stylesheets -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/css/icons/icomoon/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/css/core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/css/components.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/css/colors.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- /global stylesheets -->

    <!-- Core JS files -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.5/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- /core js files -->

    <!-- Bootstrap Validator -->
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/dist/validator.min.js"></script>
    <!-- /bootstrap validator -->

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Main navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <h1 class="text-center">
            <asp:Label ID="lblOrganizationName" runat="server" /></h1>
    </div>
    <!-- /main navbar -->


    <!-- Page container -->
    <div class="page-container">

        <!-- Page content -->
        <div class="page-content">

            <!-- Main content -->
            <div class="content-wrapper">

                <!-- Content area -->
                <div class="content">

                    <div class="row">
                        <form runat="server" id="frmNewAccount">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="panel panel-default">

                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                            <h5 class="panel-title">Account Information</h5>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="panel-body">

                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label>First Name: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                        <input type="text" autofocus name="fldMainFirst" class="form-control" maxlength="15" placeholder="First Name" tabindex="1" runat="server" id="txtAccount1First" />
                                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label>Last Name: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                        <input type="text" name="fldMainLast" class="form-control" maxlength="20" placeholder="Last Name" tabindex="2" id="txtAccount1Last" runat="server" />
                                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label>Secondary First Name:</label>
                                                        <input type="text" name="fldSecondaryFirst" class="form-control" maxlength="15" placeholder="Secondary First Name" tabindex="3" id="txtAccount2First" runat="server" data-secondarycompareprimary="" />
                                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label>Secondary Last Name: </label>
                                                        <input type="text" name="fldSecondaryLast" class="form-control" maxlength="20" placeholder="Secondary Last Name" tabindex="4" id="txtAccount2Last" runat="server" data-secondarycompareprimary="" />
                                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="text-center">
                                                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" runat="server" tabindex="20" type="submit">Add Account</button>
                                                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmitAfterValidation" runat="server" style="display: none" type="button" onserverclick="ValidateAndSaveForm">Add Account</button>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </form>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /content area -->

            </div>
            <!-- /main content -->

        </div>
        <!-- /page content -->

    </div>
    <!-- /page container -->

</body>

    <script>

    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        var validator = $('#frmNewAccount').data('bootstrapValidator');
        validator.validate();
        if (validator.isValid()) {
            $("#<%=btnSubmitAfterValidation.ClientID%>").click();
        }
    });


    $('#frmNewAccount').bootstrapValidator({

        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },


        fields: {
            txtAccount1First: {
                validators: {
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 2,
                    },
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please supply your first name'
                    }
                }
            },

            txtAccount1Last: {
                validators: {
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 2,
                    },
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please supply your last name'
                    }
                }
            },

        }

    })


    $('#frmNewAccount').validator({

        custom: {
            equals: function ($el) {
                var matchValue = $el.data("equals")
                if ($el.val() !== matchValue) {
                    return "Hey, that's not valid! It's gotta be " + matchValue
                }
            },

            secondarycompareprimary: function () {
                var fldFirstMain = $.trim($('#txtAccount1First').val());
                var fldLastMain = $.trim($('#txtAccount1Last').val());
                var fldFirstSecondary = $.trim($('#txtAccount2First').val());
                var fldLastSecondary = $.trim($('#txtAccount2Last').val());

                if (fldFirstMain == fldFirstSecondary && fldLastMain == fldLastSecondary) {
                    return "Primary & Secondary Names cannot be the same"
                }
            }

        },

    })

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this sample fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8vQFd/

```
<form id="myform">

    <input type="text" name="field1" />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="field2" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<a id="docs" href="http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation" target="_blank">Validation Documentation</a>

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true
            },
            field2: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });

});

.error {
    //border: 2px solid #f00;
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: I cannot get that to work at all. Plus, it does not have the 'custom' validators included that I need.

Comment: I did get this to work, but again, does not show how to incorporate the custom validators. I tried to incorporate in my code, but the text still shows up gray. Thanks.